# Is displaying http response possible with libgdx?

Tags: http, libgdx, httpresponse, httpwebresponse

I have written a multiplayer game using Libgdx and I would like to add a facebook login option. On the server side, I am using NodeJS and PassportJS to validate requests. So far I am able to send and receive HTTP requests using Libgdx's HttpRequest and HttpResponseListener.

My question is, is Libgdx able to display an http response in a way that a browser would? If not, I don't see how user will be able to confirm facebook permissions since I cannot show them the response they get from the facebook. I would greatly appreciate if someone can tell me how this would work. (As far as I know, nodejs redirects user to a facebook page, so I will be getting an http content to my code in Libgdx)

Note: I aim to use the application both in ios android and desktop.